# How to change constant bounds in double integral into polar.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

for example consider:

$$I:=\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

Now let’s say I want to convert to polar. How would my bounds change? The only examples I’ve seen and could find, have been when the bounds are functions of an integration variable. I understand how to do it in that case, but I am having trouble figuring out how to convert constant bounds in terms of $r$ and $\theta$.

Help is appreciated!

Also, any recourses to better learn this topic is appreciated as well if one feels so inclined as to do so.

Comment: Draw pictures. Label the sides if the rectangles with their equations in polar coordinates. Find the $\theta$ values of the four vertices. Unless you are very fortunate, you will need to break the integral into three (or more?) pieces.

Comment: @TedShifrin Even though it's short that should be an answer.